# внося данные в БД на php сразу узнать id записи у которого включен AUTO_INCREMENT

Tags: php

на php добавить в базу данных и сразу узнать id у которого включен AUTO_INCREMENT, т.е например пишу:

```
 mysqli_query($CONNECT, "INSERT INTO `name` VALUES('', 'lexa')");
```

только такая вещь как тут же написать последний id в базе данных не подходит, так как вдруг одновременно пользователи будут вносить данные. как узнать id этой записи подскажите пожалуйста??

Comment: Смело используйте mysqli_insert_id(). Другие пользователи вам не помеха — инфа 100% )

Comment: неподскажите как значение id  в переменную засунуть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id :

> The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis. This means that the value returned by the function to a given client is the first AUTO_INCREMENT value generated for most recent statement affecting an AUTO_INCREMENT column by that client. This value cannot be affected by other clients, even if they generate AUTO_INCREMENT values of their own. This behavior ensures that each client can retrieve its own ID without concern for the activity of other clients, and without the need for locks or transactions.

Т. е. сколько бы клиентов не было подключено к базе, они не могут повлиять на значение `LAST_INSERT_ID()` для текущего соединения. Таким образом функция `mysqli_insert_id($link)` вернет последний `id` верный для текущего соединения и будет возвращать его, пока вы не измените его используя `INSERT` или `UPDATE`, не взирая на вносимые изменения другими клиентами.

Comment: спасибо, а можете помочь записать id  в переменную, ни как не получается, пишу:
mysqli_query($CONNECT, "INSERT INTO `name` VALUES('', 'lexa')");
printf ("значение id %d\n", mysqli_insert_id());

выдает "значение id 0"

в БД строка записывается и  AUTO_INCREMENT в ней тоже работает норм

Comment: а нужно еще и в переменную все засунуть, подскажите пожалуста

Comment: а блин про $link не забыл, все разобрался